# Linux bash. for loop and function, for adding numbers

Tags: linux, bash, function, for-loop

I'm learning bash script's in Linux and I wanted to solve one problem that I thought it would be easy but I just cant figure it out.

I want to insert number as a parameter for example:

```
sh script.sh 5
```

And I want to get result 15 if I insert 5 (1+2+3+4+5)=15

I want to solve it with function.

```
n=$1
result=0
j=0

ADD(){
    result=`expr $result + $j`
}

#for (( i=1; i<=$n; i++ ))
for i in {0..$n..1}
do 
    ADD
    j=`expr $j + $1`
done 

echo $result
```

Every time when I want to add number I want to call function for adding.
I have no idea if I even imagined right.
And I don't know how to use for loop's. I've tried two different for loop's and I think they are not working correctly.

Comment: Use `j=$(( $j + $i ))`; `expr` is only required in very old shells that do not support the POSIX arithmetic expression syntax.

Comment: This part is wrong: `{0..$n..1}` -- bash does brace expansion before variable expansion, so you can't put variables in a range like that (without messing around with eval).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try this:

```
n=$1

sum=0
for i in `seq 1 $n` ; do
    ## redefine variable 'sum' after each iteration of for-loop
    sum=`expr $sum + $i`
done

echo $sum
```

Comment: Thank you, you'r idea helped me a lot. I just rearranged a little to work with function.

Comment: Can you explain to me what this do -> `seq 1 $n` ?

Comment: `seq` prints a sequence of numbers, so `seq 1 $n` will print `1 2 ... n` where `n` was defined as 5 when you ran **script.sh**

Comment: `seq` is necessary because `bash` processes brace expansion before parameter expansion, so `{...}` must contain only numeric literals.

Answer (score 3):

With a while loop and similar to your code:

```
#!/bin/bash

n=$(expr $1 + 1)
result=0
j=0

add(){
    result=$(expr $result + $j)
}

while test $j -ne $n
do
    add
    j=$(expr $j + 1)
done

echo $result
```

The $(..whatever..) is similar to `..whatever..`, it executes your command and returns the value. The test command is very usefull, check out the man. In this case simulates a for loop comparing the condition $j -ne $n (j not equal n) and adding 1 to the j var in each turn of the loop.

Answer (score 1):

You could try below:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

sumit() {
    local n=$1
    local sum=0
    for (( i=0;i<=n;i++ )) ; do
        (( sum = sum + i ))
    done

    echo "$sum"
}

sum=$(sumit $1)
echo "sum is ($sum)"
```

Answer (score 1):

A typical way :

```
function summation()
{
    sum=0
    for((i=m; i<=n; i++))
    {
      sum=$((sum+i)) 
    }
    echo $sum
}

read m n;
summation $m $n
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a tricky version:

```
sum_to () ( 
    set -- $(seq $1)
    IFS=+
    echo "$*" | bc
)

sum=$(sum_to 5)
echo $sum         # => 15
```

That's very slow for large numbers though:

```
$ time sum_to 1000000
500000500000

real    0m2.545s
user    0m2.513s
sys 0m0.189s
```

More efficient

```
$ sum_to_2 () { { seq $1 | tr '\n' '+'; echo 0; } | bc; }
$ time sum_to_2 1000000
500000500000

real    0m0.727s
user    0m0.981s
sys 0m0.037s
```

Better:

```
$ sum_to_3 () { perl -le '$n=$ARGV[0]; $sum += $n-- while $n; print $sum' $1; }
$ time sum_to_3 1000000
500000500000

real    0m0.075s
user    0m0.071s
sys 0m0.002s
```

Worser: invoking an "external" program for each number

```
$ sum_to_slow () { 
    sum=0
    for i in $(seq $1); do
        sum=$(expr $sum + $i)
    done
    echo $sum
}
$ date; time sum_to_slow 1000000; date
Mon Mar 17 14:00:53 EDT 2014
^C
$ date
Mon Mar 17 14:07:01 EDT 2014
```

I hit Ctrl-C after a few  minutes with no answer in sight. At least do the arithmetic in bash

```
$ sum_to_slow_improved () { sum=0; for i in $(seq $1); do (( sum += i )); done; echo $sum; }
$ time sum_to_slow_improved 1000000
500000500000

real    0m4.937s
user    0m4.869s
sys 0m0.124s
```

Still 2 orders of magnitude slower than the Perl version